# Remove hour, minute and second from a date('r")

Tags: php, date, mktime

I have a date with this format :

```
date("r",$dateMktime);
```

In $dateMktime, i only have year, month and day and i'm obliged to use date("r") format.

How can i remove hour, minute and seconde ? I don't want to see 00:00:00 when i echo my date.

Any idea ? Thanks :)

Edit : I can't use a different format, it's an obligation to use date('r'), i can only do echo date("r",$dateMktime);

Comment: Uhm... don't use `r`, but another format...?

Comment: obligated? So this is a school exercise ?

Comment: No, i use a CMS, and this format is an obligation ... ^^

Comment: weird CMS then... consider a different one?

Comment: I'm confused. If you can't just use a different date format, what do you intend to do to change the string that date('r'..) returns? Do a str_replace or something, but surely then you have access to the code and therefore __can__ use a different format?

Comment: The question deserves more -ves than the answers have gotten

Comment: I don't know, maybe an option exist with date("r") for remove hour..

Comment: Can you explain WHY your obligated to use 'r'?

Comment: I'm 99% sure that all you want is to get a string that looks like `Wed, 05 Sep 2012`, even if you don't use the `r` format code to obtain it.

Comment: I CAN'T USE A DIFFERENT FORMAT ! I try a way to remove these infos for this format.

Comment: answer below... => `implode(" ",array_slice(explode(" ",date("r",$dateMktime)),0,4));`

Answer (score 2):

Why not reconverting and then formatting ? If you are "obligated" to use `r` ?

```
$date = date("r", $dateMktime);
echo date('D, j M Y', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: This seems like the best option but in doing this you may as well just not use 'r' in the first place. This question is void.

Comment: But if he wants to use `r`, let him reformat ..

Answer (score 0):

Well according to [the documentation of date](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), `date('r')` does include the time. Use `date('Y-m-d')` instead. If you can't change it, you could remove the rest using [string functions](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
$date=date("r",$dateMktime);
$d=explode(" ",$date);
$newdate=$d[0]." ".$d[1]." ".$d[2]." ".$d[3];
echo $date." - ".$newdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like;

```
$dateMktime = "Thu, 21 Dec 2000 16:01:07 +0200";
$datearray = (explode(" ",$dateMktime));
echo $datearray[3];//this will return 2000
```

You can join specific parts of this array to get your custom date format. For example;

```
echo $datearray[1]." ".$datearray[2]." ".$datearray[3];//this will return 21 Dec 2000
```

Answer (score -1):

"r" is just a shortcut to give a date formatted as "Thu, 21 Dec 2000 16:01:07 +0200".

You can use another format string, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for more information.

Try `date("D, j M Y",$dateMktime);`.

If you really want to use `date("r",$dateMktime);`, try:

```
implode(" ",array_slice(explode(" ",date("r",$dateMktime)),0,4));
```

This basically just splits on the spaces, slices out the first 4 tokens, and joins them back up.